# Respectful terms of address (to someone you know)?

Tags: from-english, non-native-speaker

How would a Ukrainian person respectfully address someone much older than them? That is, someone who **isn't** a stranger (e.g. an elderly neighbour, teacher, etc).

Is it пані/ пан [surname] like in English?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [“Ukrainian formal/professional direct address”](/q/1046)?

Answer (score 6):

There's two possible ways to address not a strange older person in Ukrainian:

1. By saying "пані / пан [name]" (name in a [vocative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case)) (most of the cases of non-formal communication).

Example: - Пані Ірино, як просувається ваша нова стаття?

2. By saying " [name] [patronym][2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) " in a vocative case (some (more and more rare) cases for people who are *more* older and are used to patronyms and there's no reason to break their habits).

Example: - Ірино Михайлівно, чи не могли б ви мені якнайскорше відповісти щодо цього питання?